# How to forward WAN SSH server to Router for LAN users?

Tags: iptables

I have a multi-WAN network. The default gateway is router0. And I use router1 here to connect a restricted network.

```
WAN: 172.16.5.0/24
LAN: 192.168.1.0/24
router0: 192.168.1.1, [Internet], default gw [Internet]
router1: 192.168.1.3(eth2), 172.16.5.6(eth0), default gw 172.16.5.254
```

I want to forward a WAN SSH server 10.1.2.3:22 to 192.168.1.3:999 for LAN users.
Of cource the WAN provides route from 172.16.5.6 to 10.1.2.3 via 172.16.5.254.

---

I set these `iptables` on router1, but it does not work:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 999 -i eth2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:22:22
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -s 10.1.2.3:22 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.1.3:999
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you are asking for but I think you are looking just for that:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.3 -p tcp --dport 999 -i eth2 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.1.2.3:22:22
```

As the traffic passes through the box and leaves the box over DIFFERENT interface (eth0), you don't need any other rules, the returning packets will be properly handled and modified when they pass back through the box.

Please note that the server MUST have a route to get back to the originating client. If this is not the case (server doesn't have route to client), only then you need SNAT, and you likely need outgoing interface address as the source:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 10.1.2.3 -p tcp --dport 22 -j SNAT --to-source 172.16.5.6
```